# java library to extract descriptors of an image

Tags: java, image, extract, descriptor

I've done lots of researches to find a library with predefined functions that detect the descriptors of an image(color, form, texture) like the dominant color, Gabor Filtring ..
I've found more than one library but they are all used with c++
if anyone know any library to use with java language I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org)

To use it from java code, use [IM4JAVA](http://im4java.sourceforge.net)

Also check this article: "[Determining dominant color](http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/04/determining-dominant-image-color.html)"

Comment: sorry for disturbing again but I've checked those articles and done some researches. ImageMagick doesn't really compare 2 images. I want to extract the descriptors of an image in order to store it in a database
i haven't found inbuilt functions that extract the features

Comment: ImageMagick has [compare feature](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php). Also ImageMagick has [functionality to get image information](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php). All these features can be invoked from java code using IM4JAVA library. Check [IM4Java API Docs](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/api/) especially [CompareCmd](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/api/org/im4java/core/CompareCmd.html) and [IdentifyCmd](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/api/org/im4java/core/IdentifyCmd.html) classes.